# Filter list of tuples by maximum element

Tags: haskell

userDatabase is a list that consists of a tuples such as (id, username, password). How can I filter the list by using the maximum id? What I have at the moment is doing nothing but I thought I include it for some context.

```
newUser :: UserDatabase -> UserDatabase
newUser usrdb = filter (\(usrid,_,_) -> usrid == (maximum [x | (x, _, _) <- userdb])) userdb
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Have you tried `Data.List.maximumBy`?

Comment: @Rhymoid I've edited the question by I thought that it didn't explicitly need a question.

Comment: @bheklilr I'm very new to haskell and I have done some looking into maximumBy by i'm not sure how to use it and cannot find much documentation

Comment: As a side note, that type signature is invalid. Things that begin with a lowercase letter in type signatures are type variables, concrete types must begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks for that but that was just a typo. Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are all the usrid values distinct?  In that case, there is only one maximum so you can do something like:

```
type User = (Int, String, String)
type UserDatabase = [User]

fst3 (x, _y, _z) = x

userHigh :: UserDatabase -> User
userHigh = maximumBy (comparing fst3)
```

If the ids are not distinct, you might have some ties, so you'll want to return a list

```
usersHigh :: UserDatabase -> [User]
usersHigh = concat . take 1
          . groupBy (on (==) fst3)
          . sortBy (flip $ comparing fst3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just did a simple test with that and it worked. I will work on it more tomorrow but it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should get you going:

```
maximumBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe a
maximumBy extract [] = Nothing
maximumBy extract (x:xs) = go x xs
    where go candidate [] = Just candidate
          go candidate (x:xs)
              | extract x > extract candidate = go x xs
              | otherwise = go candidate xs
```

**EDIT:** Oh, bhelkir points out this function already exists in the libraries.  Anyway, a few points:

1. If you're trying to get just one item from the list, it's not a `filter` operation, it's more like a `find` or `minimum`/`maximum` operation.
2. The way you'd use this is something like this: `maximumBy (\(usrid,_,_) -> usrid) users`.  The first argument to `maximumBy` is a function that extracts the comparison field from the elements of the list.

Comment: I've tried messing around with the maximumBy and and I'm getting a strange error:    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t0 = (t0, t1, t2) -> Ordering

Comment: @user3870660 That comment sound like maybe another question, about typechecking.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. To note I removed type signature to get that error and when using `newUser :: UserDatabase -> User` I get: `Couldn't match type Int' with User -> Ordering'
    Expected type: User -> Ordering
      Actual type: UserID`

Comment: Note that the maximumBy in the answer has a significantly different type than [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:maximumBy) from the standard library, so you'll invoke them differently.

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of type `[(X, (R, R))]` (a list of tuples, where 2<sup>nd</sup> element is a tuple too), where `X` and `R` are some arbitrary types, and `R` is a member of typeclass `Ord`. Example of such list: `[(0, (0,1)), (1, (1,1)), (2, (0,0)), (3, (1,0))]`. Imagine I want to find all elements of this list, where the first element of the second element (that is, the left element of an inner tuple) is maximal. But I don't want just one such element, I want all elements, where a left element of an inner pair is maximal. So my function, called on the above list, should return `[(1, (1,1)), (3, (1,0))]`. [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) wouldn't work, because it would return only one element. So I wrote a variation of `maximumBy`, which returns multiple maximum values:

```
maximumByM :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
maximumByM c (x:xs) = maximumByM' c xs [x]
  where maximumByM' _ [] acc = acc
        maximumByM' c (x:xs) acc@(a:_) = case x `c` a of
          LT -> maximumByM' c xs acc
          EQ -> maximumByM' c xs (x:acc)
          GT -> maximumByM' c xs [x]
```

Suffix -M means “multiple”. This multiple-valued function returns a list of all values that are maximal (according to a custom comparison):

```
maximumByM compare [1,2,3] -- [3]
maximumByM compare [1,2,3,1,2,3] -- [3,3]
maximumByM (comparing fst) [(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2)] -- [(6,2),(6,1)]
maximumByM (comparing snd) [(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2)] -- [(6,2),(5,2)]
```

To implement `minimumByM` all you need to do is to [flip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) the comparator, because `compare 1 2 == (flip compare) 2 1`:

```
maximumByM (flip $ comparing fst) [(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2)] -- [(5,2),(5,1)]
-- the below 2 are equivalent due to Haskell's currying
minimumByM = maximumByM . flip
minimumByM c xs = maximumByM (flip c) xs
```

Unfortunately `maximumByM` returns the list in reversed order. I could add `reverse` in code, but this double work? And explicit recursion? Why not implement the same function using [right fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldr):

```
maximumByM :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
maximumByM _ [] = []
maximumByM c (x:xs) = foldr f [x] xs
  where f = (\e acc@(a:_) -> case c e a of
              LT -> acc
              EQ -> e:acc
              GT -> [e])
```

Now it returns the list in the same order as elements are found in the original list:

```
maximumByM (comparing fst) [(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2)] -- [(6,1),(6,2)]
```

Of course, you could use [Boyd Stephen Smith Jr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24922586/596361)'s approach, combining [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) and [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) (`sortBy` requires `flip` because it sorts from small to big):

```
maximumByM :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
maximumByM _ [] = []
maximumByM c xs = head $ groupBy ((==EQ) .: c) $ sortBy (flip c) xs
  where (.:) = (.).(.) -- x .: y = \a b -> x(y a b)
```

You don't need to reverse the list, because `sortBy` will preserve the order of elements it deems equal:

```
maximumByM (comparing fst) [(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2)] -- [(6,1),(6,2)]
```